# A question from the proof of the Tietze's Extension Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

**Tietze's Extension Theorem:**  Suppose $X$ is a metric space and $S$ is a closed subset of $X$. Suppose $f \in C(S,\mathbb R)$, where $C(S,\mathbb R)$ refers to the space of bounded continuous functions from $S \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Then $~\exists ~\bar f \in C(X, \mathbb R)$ such that $\bar f_{|S} = f, \inf \bar f(X) = \inf f(S), \sup \bar f(X) = \sup f(S)$.

> **Lemma used in the proof** :~ Suppose $X$ is a metric space and $S$ is a closed subset of $X$. Suppose $f \in C(S,\mathbb R)$ is not constant.  Let $a = \inf f(S), ~b= \sup f(S) , ~k = \dfrac {b-a}{3}$ Then, there exists a function $f^+$ that has the properties : $f^+(X) \subseteqq [a+k,b-k], \inf (f-f^+)(S) = -k,~ \sup (f-f^+)(S)=k$

**Proof:** If $F$ is constant, the result is trivial. So, we suppose otherwise.

Define $h_1 = f^+$.

**Step $1$:** Given that $f : S \rightarrow [a,b]$ is a continuous function. Then : we know that $\sup (f-f^+)(S) = k , \inf ( f - f^+)(S) = -k$

**$\therefore f - h_1 = f - f^+$ is a function from  $S \rightarrow [-k,k]$ and $f-f^+ \in C(S,\mathbb R)$.**

**Step $2$ :** Applying the same process to the function $f - f^+ = f - h_1$, we get :

$a' = -k, ~b' = k, k'=\dfrac {2k}{3}$ w.r.t $[-k,k]$

$h_2 = (f-h_1)^+$

By using the relations mentioned in the lemma: We get : $\inf (f-h_1-h_2)= -\dfrac{2k}{3}, \sup (f-h_1-h_2)= \dfrac {2k}{3}. $

$\therefore f-h_1-h_2 :S  \rightarrow [-\dfrac {2k}{3}, \dfrac {2k}{3} ]$

$\therefore k'' = \dfrac {4k}{3 \cdot 3} = \dfrac {4k}{9}$

Applying step $1$ again, let $h_3 = (f-h_1-h_2)^+$

In the same way, we obtain a sequence $(h_n)$ with the property that $h_n= (f-h_1-h_2 - \cdots h_{n-1})^+$ and  : $\inf (f-h_1-h_2 - \cdots h_n)= -\dfrac {2^{n-1}k}{3^{n-1}}, \sup (f-h_1-h_2 - \cdots h_n) = \dfrac {2^{n-1}k}{3^{n-1}}$

and $h_n \in [-\dfrac {2^{n-1}k}{3^{n}}, \dfrac {2^{n-1}k}{3^{n}}]$

**Step $3$:** Let $s_n= h_1+ \cdots h_n$.

Then $(s_n)$ is a cauchy sequence in $C(X,\mathbb R)$ since $|s_m-s_n| \le |h_1| + \cdots |h_n| \le (2/3)^n k$

Since $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is complete $(s_n)$ converges to some $\bar f \in C(X,\mathbb R)$

> **Step $4$** : Now, we claim that $\bar f$ is a desired extension of $f$. It is in this step where I am encountering problem understanding.

Since, $|f - h_1 - \cdots - h_n| \le (2/3)^n k \implies s_n \rightarrow \bar f$ uniformily on $A$

> BUT, $|s_n| \le |h_1| + \cdots + |h_n| \le \dfrac {k}{3} ( 1 + \dfrac {2}{3} + {(\dfrac {2}{3}})^2 + \cdots )= k \implies \bar f_{|S} \in [-k,k]$. But, the range of $\bar f$ on $A$ should be $[a,b]$ which means $\bar f$ is clearly not the desired extension.

Please help me understanding where I could be wrong?. Thanks a lot for reading through!

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Yes, changed it. thanks

Comment: @theoreticalEconomist I have changed it. Do you think there's a flaw in the proof?

Comment: there’s clearly an error somewhere... I’ve read the entire question but I can’t see it, unfortunately. I’ll try to read more carefully and let you know if I find something.

Comment: Any help from anybody will be deeply appreciated as I have been stuck since three days on this

Comment: Note that the actual range is not so imporatant. If the range of $f$ is $[a, b]$, then by the range of $g ∘ f$ is $[-1, 1]$ for suitable affine map $g$. So without loss of generality, range $f$ is $[-1, 1]$. That may simplify the proof a bit.

Comment: @user87690 okay.. But then, would we still be able to call it an extension though? Thanks

Comment: @MathMan sure, formally you extend this $g ∘ f$ and then compose with $g^{-1}$. That would be desired extension of the original $f$. This argument shows that it is really without loss of generality to consider $f$ onto $[-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where do you take your last equation from. While it is true that $\|f-h_1\|=k$, the range of $h_1$ is inside $[a+k,b-k]$ and $\|h_1\|=\max\{|a+k|,|b+k|\}$.

By the Lemma the range of $h_2$ is inside $[-k+k',k-k']=[-k/3,k/3]$. Hence the range of $h_1+h_2$ lies inside $[a+k-k/3,b-k+k/3]=[a+(2/3)k,b-(2/3)k]$.

Then for every $n$ from the fact that the range of $h_n$ (**for $n$ greater than $1$**!!!) is inside $[-2^{n-1}k/3^n, 2^{n-1}k/3^n]$ you may derive that the range of $h_1+\cdots+h_n$ lies inside $[a+k-k/3-\cdots-2^{n-1}k/3^n, b-k+k/3+\cdots+2^{n-1}k/3^n]=[a+(2/3)^n k, b-(2/3)^n k]$.

Comment: Could you please help me show that the range of  $s_n$ is inside $[a+(2/3)^n k, b-(2/3)^n k]$ . I have tried to prove it in my proof as well and i get the range as $[-k,k]$. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MathMan I changed my answer to give more detail.